# List of arrays to array of arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a List of arrays of integers. I want to convert it to an array of arrays of integers, but when using `toArray()` I get the error `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[I`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
public int[][] getCells() {
    List<int[]> cells = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int y = this.y0; y <= this.y1 ; y++) {
        for (int x = this.x0; x <= this.x1 ; x++) {
            cells.add(new int[]{x, y});
        }
    }

    return (int[][]) cells.toArray();
}
```

**EDIT**

I've seen that in this case I can convert it with:

```
return cells.toArray(new int[cells.size()][2]);
```

But only because all the integer arrays have the same size (2). What If I don't know it? Thanks

Comment: How are you storing the return value of this function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call

```
cells.toArray(new int[cells.size()][])
```

Your old call `cells.toArray()` does not work since this creates an array of objects `Object[]` which apparently cannot be cast to `int[][]`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
    return (int[][])cells.toArray(new int[cells.size()][]);
```

Or use just:

```
    return cells.toArray(new int[][]{});
```

Instead of:

```
    return (int[][]) cells.toArray();
```